# How to maintain the state of button in ng-repeat when i reload the page

Tags: html, angularjs

I have some code that lists out items in a table from a database. The click function toggles the cells between green and red. When I click the row it will take me to detail page through ng-route. When I navigate back to the same page I need to maintain the state of the name or the division selected before?

```html
<tr ng-repeat="team in Pool" ng-click("Navigate to team detail page")>
  <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': namestarted[$index],
                'btn-success': !namestarted[$index]}"
      ng-click="changeColor(team.chrTeamName, $index)">{{ team.chrTeamName }}</td>
  <td>{{ team.intSeed }}</td>
  <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': divstarted[$index],
                'btn-success': !divstarted[$index]}"
      ng-click="changeColor(team.chrDivision, $index)">{{ team.chrDivision }}</td>
</tr> 


Controller:


$scope.namestarted = [];
$scope.divstarted = [];

$scope.changeColor= function (status, index) {
  if(status == "Name"){    
    $scope.namestarted [index] = !$scope.namestarted [index];}
  else
    $scope.divstarted [index] = !$scope.divstarted [index];
}
```